# geomesa add-attribute-index fails

Tags: hadoop, geomesa

I am trying to add an [index](http://www.geomesa.org/documentation/1.3.2/user/accumulo/commandline_tools.html#add-attribute-index) to my existing table using the following command (run inside accumulo-master docker image)

```
geomesa add-attribute-index -u root -p secret -i gis -z SERVER_IP -c posiciones   -f posicion -a id_posicion --coverage join
```

But it does not work and produce this output:

```
INFO  Running map reduce index job for attributes: [id_posicion] with coverage: join...
ERROR Error encountered running attribute index command. Check hadoop's job history logs for more information.
```

The hadoop job log is the following:

```
2017-09-17 20:39:48,253 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Created MRAppMaster for application appattempt_1505353025896_0020_000002
2017-09-17 20:39:48,706 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2017-09-17 20:39:48,757 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Executing with tokens:
2017-09-17 20:39:49,079 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Kind: YARN_AM_RM_TOKEN, Service: , Ident: (appAttemptId { application_id { id: 20 cluster_timestamp: 1505353025896 } attemptId: 2 } keyId: -1893920016)
2017-09-17 20:39:49,094 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: Using mapred newApiCommitter.
2017-09-17 20:39:49,095 INFO [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster: OutputCommitter set in config org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DirectFileOutputCommitter
2017-09-17 20:39:49,173 INFO [main]    org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService: Service org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster failed in state INITED; cause: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class  org.apache.accumulo.core.client.mapreduce.AccumuloOutputFormat not found
org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.YarnRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.accumulo.core.client.mapreduce.AccumuloOutputFormat not found
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$2.call(MRAppMaster.java:519)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$2.call(MRAppMaster.java:499)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.callWithJobClassLoader(MRAppMaster.java:1594)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.createOutputCommitter(MRAppMaster.java:499)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.serviceInit(MRAppMaster.java:284)
at org.apache.hadoop.service.AbstractService.init(AbstractService.java:163)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$5.run(MRAppMaster.java:1552)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.initAndStartAppMaster(MRAppMaster.java:1549)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster.main(MRAppMaster.java:1482)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.accumulo.core.client.mapreduce.AccumuloOutputFormat not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2195)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getOutputFormatClass(JobContextImpl.java:223)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.MRAppMaster$2.call(MRAppMaster.java:516)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.accumulo.core.client.mapreduce.AccumuloOutputFormat not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2101)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
... 13 more
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a bug - the jars to load are defined in this [file](https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/blob/master/geomesa-accumulo/geomesa-accumulo-jobs/src/main/resources/org/locationtech/geomesa/jobs/accumulo-libjars.list). Likely the file needs to be updated for newer versions of accumulo - the missing class now appears to be in the `accumulo-core` jar. You should be able to fix it by adding the line `accumulo-core` to that file, which ends up in `lib/geomesa-accumulo-jobs-<version>.jar` in the tools distribution.

Comment: I had to add both `accumulo-core` and `parboiled` to that file, but I verified that it works with those changes. I've put up a PR for the fix here: https://github.com/locationtech/geomesa/pull/1700

Answer (score 0):

Is $ACCUMULO_HOME set?  And are other geomesa commands working?

Setting $ACCUMULO_HOME to point to a copy of the Accumulo distribution would likely help.  If you are using the GeoMesa tools from a machine which is not part of the cluster, then you can use the install-hadoop-accumulo.sh script in the tools distribution to download a copy of the necessary dependencies to $GEOMESA_HOME/lib.

Comment: $ACCUMULO_HOME is set correctly. If I run geomesa describe-schema -u root -i user -p pass -c posiciones -f posicion  it works without problems.